# Проблемы с No module named aiogram.fsm

Tags: aiogram

сидел программировал своего телеграм бота на python с помощью aiogram, у меня стоит у меня aiogram 2.x.x но не могу понять как мне пофиксить ошибку No module named 'aiogram.fsm'

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, потому что там нет aiogram.fsm. По-этому и ошибка.

Для fsm несколько импортов и они другие:

```
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
```

В [документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/v2.25.1/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html) подробно описано как использовать FSM